# Hiding a button after a purchase with MKStoreKit

Tags: ios4, in-app-purchase

Been wrangling with MKStoreKit 3.0 for the first time... and nearly everything is good for me; things purchase, userdefaults are set, I've got UIbuttons that hide after reboots.  But I seem to have tripped at a very elementary step.

How do I make my 'buy' UIbutton hide after purchases and re-purchases?  Is there a function hidden in MKStoreManager.h that I'm yet to discover? Or should I just get the buyfeature action to twiddle its fingers for a while then check to see if a purchase has happened in the intrim?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check `[MKStoreManager isFeaturePurchased:featureID]`. I'm not sure if this changed in MKStoreKit 4.0 though.

Comment: Found '- (void)productFetchComplete;'

Comment: I don't think this is what you want -- productFetchComplete is called when you get the products' description from the app store, in order to populate your interface.